# Remove all digits in a list of strings

Tags: python, list

```
words = ['Duration12', 'Noun1', 'Adjective7']
result = [word[:-2] for word in words]
```

gives me

> ['Duration', 'Nou', 'Adjectiv']

But I want to get

> ['Duration', 'Noun', 'Adjective']

Is there any library function to implement it or should I explicitly detect the digits available and then remove them?

Comment: Will the digits always be at the end of the words?

Comment: @learnerPy Check answer.

Comment: @Olivier Melançon ya. And got the answer already marked as accepted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension and remove all digits using `re.sub`:

```
import re
words = ['Duration12', 'Noun1', 'Adjective7']
[re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', w) for w in words]
```

**Result**

```
['Duration', 'Noun', 'Adjective']
```

Comment: Great to know. From curiosity i am now searching in re if  [ 'Duration[12]', 'Noun[1]', 'Adjective[7]' ] is also possible

Comment: You mean to remove also the brackets?

Comment: Use `[re.sub(r'[0-9]+', r'[\g<0>]', w) for w in words]`

Comment: for words = ['Duration12:1', 'Noun', 'Adjective7:8'] i am getting ['Duration[12]:[1]', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:[8]'] But like to have ['Duration[12]:1', 'Noun', 'Adjective[7]:8']

Answer (score 2):

Try This One:

```
In [8]: from string import digits

In [9]: remove_digits = str.maketrans('', '', digits)

In [10]: [word.translate(remove_digits) for word in words]
Out[10]: ['Duration', 'Noun', 'Adjective']
```

For more info refer to the link: [Link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the numbers, using [isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

```
words = ['Duration12', 'Noun1', 'Adjective7']

result = [''.join(c for c in w if c.isalpha()) for w in words]
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all digits are at end of words, you might use `.strip` following way:

```
words = ['Duration12', 'Noun1', 'Adjective7']
results = [i.strip('0123456789') for i in words]
print(results) #give ['Duration', 'Noun', 'Adjective']
```

but keep in mind that this method would not work if digits are inside rather than at end